# What if a US citizen kills a foreign citizen?

Tags: international, murder

What if a US citizen kills a foreign citizen in another country and in the US?

Comment: This question is too vague to tell what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

If any person (citizen or otherwise) kills any person (citizen or otherwise) in the US, they are subject to the laws of that state, or possibly the federal murder statute depending on the specific circumstances (like, "was the victim the president of the US"). The same goes for a murder outside the US – it depends on where the act took place.

There may be special cases where a country claims extraterritorial jurisdiction. For example, the US can prosecute a person for a murder that took place outside the US, if the victim is an [Internationally Protected Person](https://www.justice.gov/archives/jm/criminal-resource-manual-1617-extraterritorial-criminal-jurisdiction-18-usc-112-878-970-1116). An example is "Head of State", if the perpetrator is a US national, or is apprehended in the US. Extraterritorial prosecution exists if and only if a jurisdiction has a law allowing it, so you'd have to fill in the details. If I kill a bus driver in France, the US cannot prosecute me, but France can.

Comment: The USA are slightly unusual; they will also prosecute US citizens who murder US citizens anywhere in the world. For example if the bus driver in France happened to be a US citizen.

Comment: Also if you kill an internationally protected person in France, the US normally won't prosecute you if France does.  Even if the IPP is a bus driver :-) (this may be unlikely perhaps in France, but it is quite possible in some places).

Comment: In that case France would also want to prosecute (“anyone killing anyone in France”) and whoever gets the murderer first will prosecute.

Comment: @phoog Most likely an American bus driver on holiday in France :-)